# C#: data grid view with combo box

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

So, I have a data grid view displaying some data about "employees" from a database. When I click on a record in dgv, I want a combo box to appear and allowing to select "Delete" or "Update". I created a new Form, with a singe Combo box, and checked if a row from dgv is selected, then the combo box should appear. My code for data grid view looks like:

```
 private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = -1;
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {

            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];


            string text = row.Cells["idEmployee"].Value.ToString();
            Int32.TryParse(text, out id);

            Form newCombo = new Form2();
            string var;
            var = newCombo.Text;

            if (var == "Delete")
            {
                da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("Delete from employee where idEmployee = " + id + ";", cs);

                cs.Open();
                da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cs.Close();
             }

         }

      }
```

and from Combo Box:

```
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Delete");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Update");
    }
```

but, whenever I click on a row in the data grid view, nothing happens.. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You dont show the form instance.  You could also add a "Delete" checkbox column to the DGV rather than annoy the user with a popup form.

Comment: The thing is that depending on the selected row from the DGV, the user should be able to choose whether he wants to delete or update the record... that's why I thought a combBox would be a good idea

Comment: I suggest to use Popup Menu which is easier to implement. You can pop the popup Menu in code-behind when user clicks on a row in your dgv.

Comment: Or you could add button columns.